# Storing data in memory for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, discord.js

I have a small question idk if it's a dumb question or not. when coding some logic for a discord bot that will be used in several, you'll often come to a point were you should you store some global variables or inside a function. My question is, doesn't this storing of data in memory, will cause memory issue, since the bot will be used in multiple servers?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're better off using a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be possible to cause a "memory issue", so to speak. If you saved data from a guild to a variable every time a user used a command (even from different guilds), then the old value would simply be completely overwritten by the data from the new guild.

If what you're asking about is how data from different guilds is stored at the same time, then your answer is that the discord.js client simply stores a copy of every guild's data that the bot is in, in the [`client.guilds.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache) property. If you want to get a certain guild's data you can simply use `client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)`.

Of course, note that when you store anything in memory, the data will be lost when you shut off the bot. That's what @Elitezen was talking about; to persist data between sessions you need a dedicated database.